# Magento writes Empty needle warning every 5 minutes

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, zend-framework

I am trying to understand if what I am seeing is causing any kind of issue in the store, and If there is a need to take an action?

I can see in my system.log below 2 lines are being written once every 5 minutes :

```
 Warning: strpos(): Empty needle  in /home/XXX/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 508

 Warning: strpos(): Empty needle  in /home/XXX/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php on line 514
```

In **Http.php** line 508 I have the below code:

```
        if (0 === strpos($requestUri, $baseUrl)) {
            // full $baseUrl matches
            $this->_baseUrl = $baseUrl;
            return $this;
        }
```

and in Line 514 is :

```
       if (0 === strpos($requestUri, dirname($baseUrl))) {
            // directory portion of $baseUrl matches
            $this->_baseUrl = rtrim(dirname($baseUrl), '/');
            return $this;
        }
```

Because I have no clue about this issue at all, I thought it migth be related to **cron job** since it is configured to run every 5 minutes, but cron job is working as expected. (at least I can see emails are being delivered, and the cron job table in db is changing)

I have the cron job command like below:

```
     php -f /home/XXXX/public_html/cron.php
```

P.S : I am not using any load balancer. The store is running on a single url with different parameter to determine the Website. E.X: www.xxx.com/us and www.xxx.com/uk

Comment: $baseUrl is empty. You use load balancing? or proxy?

Comment: No, I am not using any load balancer or Proxy, but I am using multi website/store.

Comment: With several different domain name?

Comment: It's running under same domain name. The stores are Separated using "/". So it's like example.com/us and example.com/uk

Comment: If using Aoe_Scheduler please read here: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/issues/233

Comment: @sv3n, You are right. Would be great, If you could help to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Aoe_Scheduler please read here: http://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/issues/233

> update:
>
> changes in scheduler_cron.sh seems to fix it:
>
> from:
>
> ```
> PHP_BIN=$(which php || true)
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> PHP_BIN=$(which php-cli || true)
> ```
>
> also 5cc0cb4 isn't necessary any more!